# Can an HTML5/javascript Android app access the camera/voice recorder?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm thinking of getting into Android app development and I hear HTML5 apps are becoming more popular now. Can HTML5 + javascript be used to access media inputs on the phone, or is this only available to Java apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frameworks like Phonegap make this possible by providing a wrapper around the api of each device it supports, which can be called from your html5 application built using it. Check their site [here](http://phonegap.com/about) or their api documentation for the camera api [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html).

Answer (score 3):

In pure HTML5/JS, you can't.

But, you can use fameworks like Phonegap that provides JS libraries allowing you to access to the device capabilities such as GPS, camera, etc.